# jQuery: How to layer notification div float instead of insert inside a div?

Tags: jquery

here is my `ajax` call

```
// send the data to the server using .ajax() or .post()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addVideo',
            data: {
                video_title: title,
                playlist_name: playlist,
                url: id
                // csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                 bootstrap_alert.success('video saved successfully');
            },

            // callback handler that will be called on error
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                bootstrap_alert.error('There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while');
            },
        });
```

and `notification` function

```
// setting up alerts on action
bootstrap_alert = function() {}
bootstrap_alert.success = function(message) {
  $('#feature').prepend('<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success"><!--a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a--><span>'+message+'</span></div>');
  $('#alert').fadeOut(3000);
}
bootstrap_alert.error = function(message) {
  $('#feature').prepend('<div id="alert" class="alert alert-error"><!--a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a--><span>'+message+'</span></div>');
  $('#alert').fadeOut(3000);
}
```

- When I `ajax` call returns I see a div for 3 seconds and it goes away **BUT** then, my page moves up very quickly, I **want** to make this transition smooth
- is it possible to layer the notification div on top of `feature` div which disappears after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sliding effects to make it nice.  You could insert the content, slide it down, wait 3 seconds, then slide it up.

```
var x =$("<div class='alert'>Alert</div>");
$("#c1").prepend(x);
x.slideDown(250).delay(3000).slideUp(250);​
```

Sample fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/gxbTJ/15/

Answer (score 0):

You can layer it on top.
Use the CSS property [z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to used fadeOut() for the effect you're describing, but instead you'll need to write a custom [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  fadeOut() will only do the fadeOut, and then you see the browser trying to fill the empty space.  You'll need to write an animate that fades and slides if you want both.  Alternatively, you could just use just a slide with [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) or [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

To overlay your div, use some CSS like:

```
#overlay {
z-indez:6000;
position:fixed; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;   
top:0; 
left:0; 
}
```